# dplyr summarize by string

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that has numeric and string values, for example:

```
 mydf <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
               value = c(32, 12, 43, 6, 50, 20),
               text = c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```

The value of `id` variable always corresponds to `text` variable, e.g., `id == 1` will always be `text == 'A'`.

Now, I want to summarize this dataframe by `id` (or by `text`, since it's the same thing):

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(mean_value = mean(value))
```

This works nicely, but I also need the `text` variable, since I wan t to do text analysis.

However, when I add `text` to the dplyr pipe:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(mean_value = mean(value),
  text = text)
```

I get the following error:

> Error: expecting a single value

Since `text` for `id` is always the same, is it possible to append it to the summarized dataframe?

Comment: Try `group_by(id, text) %>% summarize(mean_value = mean(value))`

Comment: ok, I though I tried this, but apparently I forgot to. Yep, this works nicely, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`summarize` function needs to apply some functions on input, so we can either keep `text` out of it and keep together with `id` within `group_by`, or use `first` function within `summarize`:

```
# text should be in group_by to show up in result
mydf %>%
  group_by(id, text) %>%
  summarize(mean_value = mean(value))

# or within summarise use first function, to take the first value when grouped
mydf %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(mean_value = mean(value),
            text = first(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of summarise, which would make your df into a data frame with only two columns, use mutate so that you can keep other variables.

```
mydf %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(mean_value = mean(value))
```